# How can i save a new result from a variable using Python?

Tags: python

it's my first post here. I'm new to programming and started recently using the Python language to learn programming logic and algorithms. 
I have a problem that I am unable to solve in an basic exercise. How can I save a new variable's value?
My problem is after the IF, because he is miscalculating the time in PM

```
# Exercise 3.9 - Calculating seconds in the current month
```

```
day = int(input("Type the current day: "))
hours = int(input("Type the current hour (in 12-hour format): "))
am_pm = str(input("It's AM or PM?: "))

if (am_pm) == "PM":
    hours += 12
if (am_pm) == "AM":
    hours *= 1
minutes = int(input("Type the current minute: "))
seconds = int(input("Type the current second: "))


conversion_day = (day-1) * 86400
conversion_hours = hours * 3600
conversion_minutes = minutes * 60
conversion_seconds = seconds * 1

total = conversion_day+conversion_hours+conversion_minutes+conversion_seconds

print(f"The conversion of {day} days, {hours} hours, {minutes} minutes and {seconds} seconds resulted in {total} seconds this month! ")
```

Comment: `hours = hours + 12`…? Or `hours += 12` for short?

Comment: Could you add an example of your input and output?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You already assign lots of variables in your code. What specific problem do you have with assigning the calculated values?

Comment: I made the changes, now it works. But still has a problem, if I reply with "am" or "pm" instead of "AM" or "PM", he considers all as AM. The result with "pm" is the same as "am" or "AM".
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your revised code…?

Comment: I edited the post now with the corrections in the IF

Comment: If you enter "pm", that doesn't match "PM", so it won't enter that `if` block. It also doesn't match "AM", so it won't enter that block either. The entire "AM" block does nothing by the way and can be removed entirely. The typical solution for case sensitive user input is `if am_pm.lower() == 'pm'`.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do it by assignment, that is 
hours = hours + 12
or 
hours += 12

If you just write variable_name + value , the variable itself does not change.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value to a variable you need to use the `=` operator. In your case, you must do `hours = hours + 12`. You can also use the `+=` operator for the same result, in that case it would be `hours += 12`.

The same is true for the line just above, where you have `hours * 1`. That is not actually doing anything. You should have done `hours = hours * 1` or `hours *= 1`.

Comment: `am_pm == "AM"` is a NOOP really and should be omitted entirely…

Answer (score -1):

Both if statements will be as following,

```
if (am_pm) == "AM":
    hours *= 1

if (am_pm) == "PM":
    hours += 12
```

or you can also write them as,

```
 if (am_pm) == "AM":
        hours *= 1

 else:
        hours += 12
```

Comment: Technically if `am_pm != 'AM'` then it doesn't automatically follow that it's `'PM'`, so this `else` isn't really appropriate.